# How to test if kubernetes pod has status ready

Tags: go, kubernetes

I need to test if specific pods in existing k8s culster is ready. I was reading some stuff here and there and know which steps are necessary for me:

1. Get kubeconfig
   `config, err := clientcmd.BuildConfigFromFlags("", *kubeconfig)`
2. Connect to k8s cluster (Don't know how)
3. Since instance name is known get

`pod, _ := clientset.CoreV1().Pods("kubernetes").Get("prometheus", metav1.GetOptions{}) fmt.Println(pod.Status)`

So the problem for me is, that I don't get the bit how to connect to the cluster and finally retrieve the pod name.

I wanna add that the cluster is created and existing. The pod names and corresponding namespaces are controlled.

At some harder points I kindly ask to apply explain like I am 5.

Answer (score 0):

The cluster connection information comes from the kubeconfig file, so you need to connect to the cluster before launching your application.

In order to do so, use 'kubectl`. If your cluster is already created and running, I assume 'kubectl' is already pointing to it.

Otherwise, your code seems to be correct.

Relevant documentation:

- https://www.redhat.com/sysadmin/kubeconfig
- https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/access-cluster/